# How to change the order of the list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have below list:

[image]

Where i want to show all the records which contains Status equals to 6 at the last of the list. (*The status would be any starting from 1 to 20 for different properties.)

How can i do this?

Comment: There is no reason behind; especially when you say - `Status at last of the list`. 
It seems that it is already in alphabetic order that's why it falls at last. 
Did you intentionally put it at last position?

Comment: @Manoz, are you able to see any alphabet in list? This is what i'm getting in result. :)

Comment: I was talking about the result ;) I am not chuck norris :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you can use `OrderBy()` in the following way so that items with `Status == 6` are returned after the other items :

```
OrderBy(o => o.Status == 6 ? 1 : 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have list of items and you can show last record of this list. It should be use **LastOrDefault** function.

Comment: I want to show status equals to 6 at the last of the list, not the last records from the list :)

Comment: you have where function. Using this filtered data and display last record.

Answer (score 0):

use below code i think that will help you. and replace with your property you wan't that thank you.

```
LastOrDefault(x => x.property).where(x.status ==6)
```